# React Native - Navigation from another file

Tags: javascript, react-native

So, I'm using 2 files: The *components.js* where I define all parts and molds I'll use in my app, and the *App.js*, which has the logic and major stuff.

To sum things up, I've defined a *Card* class in the *components.js* that has a button at the end. Here is the code for the *Card*:

```
export class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{height: 700}}> 
          <View style={{flex: 8, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 20}} > 
              <Image source={{uri: this.props.pic}} style={styles.img}/> 
              <Text style={{flex: 1, fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize: 30, paddingTop: 10}}> {this.props.nome}</Text> 
              <Text style={{flex: 1, fontSize: 20}}> {this.props.descricao}</Text> 
              <TouchableHighlight style={{flex: 1}} onPress={() => ???????} underlayColor="white">
                  <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Mais informações</Text>
                  </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And I use it in the *App.js* as follows:

```
import {Card} from "./components.js";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:"#e6e6e1"}}>
      <ScrollView>
        {this.state.locations.map((pico, key) => 
          <Card key={key} pic={pico.img[0]}  nome= {pico.nome_do_pico} descricao={pico.how}/>
        )}    
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

(I've omitted the parts where it gets the info from the server and puts into the *locations* array)

What I need is for the button to navigate to another screen, called "Details", and I have tried a few things on the *onPress* but nothing has worked so far. The documentation for *reactnavigation* uses *this.state.navigation.navigate("Details")* as example, but since the *Card* is in another file it can't access the *this.state.navigation*. Any ideas?

Comment: The `navigation` object is passed to _props_ of screens registered with `react-navigaton` so the call that would navigate would be: `this.props.navigation.navigate("Details")` (unless you are mirroring props in state which is usually an anti-pattern). Having said that, there are other ways to navigate around the app if you don't have access to `navigation` prop. Have you read: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try if you can solve the problem by modifying the following part of your code:

in app.js

```
<Card key={key} pic={pico.img[0]}  nome= {pico.nome_do_pico} descricao={pico.how} navigation={navigation}/>
```

in components.js:

```
          <TouchableHighlight style={{flex: 1}} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', {YourParameters: xx } } underlayColor="white">
              <View style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Mais informações</Text>
              </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
```